# Reference ROW_NUMBER() of an outer query? Or conditionally populate fields based on whether it appeared in another returned record?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I have a query that returns records where an important_id is between a min and max value. I need to add a column to denote a record 'P' or 'I', 'P' for the first appearance of a row with an important_id and 'I' for any following record with the same important_id, and I've ordered them by important_id so the returned record should look something like

```
P_or_I |important_id | other columns...
---------------------------------------
P      | 12345       | ...                //ROW_NUMBER() returns 1
I      | 12345       | ...                //ROW_NUMBER() returns 2
I      | 12345       | ...                //ROW_NUMBER() returns 3
I      | 12345       | ...                //etc.
P      | 12346       | ...
P      | 12347       | ...
I      | 12347       | ...
I      | 12347       | ...
P      | 12348       | ...
I      | 12348       | ...
```

It maybe should be pointed out that there doesn't necessarily have to be a repeated important_id as in the above example between 12346 and 12347.

Initially the query did not return records for a range of important_id, but only a single one and the code worked fine using something like

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY important_id) = 1 THEN 'P' ELSE 'I' END, t1.important_id_1 as important_id, ..., 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.important_id_1 = t2.important_id_2 
WHERE important_id_1 = <searched for number>
ORDER BY important_id;
```

It should be noted that for all returned records denoted 'I', most of the values therein must be omitted save for important_id and a few others, and so having the ability to check the condition of ROW_NUMBER() and then deciding to populate the field or not was useful in addition to denoting 'P' or 'I'.

However, now the query must return records for a range of important_ids, and so I have attempted to modify the code by creating a #temptable that through some setup with inserting an accumulating variable with COUNT() in a WHILE is populated with values reflective of the row numbers that should be denoted 'P', so for the above example would look like

```
important_id | number_of_ids | p_record_index 
---------------------------------------------
12345        | 4             | 1
12346        | 1             | 5    //note the first 12346 in the table above is row 5
12347        | 3             | 6
12348        | 2             | 9
```

So by knowing the order of how the new query returns when a range is checked instead of a single value ordered by important_id, I hoped to simply check if ROW_NUMBER() returns a value within #temptable and then conditionally handle populating that record, but it hasn't worked as I hoped.

Here is what I thought I could do

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (EXISTS(SELECT TOP (1) FROM #temptable where p_record_index = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY important_id))) THEN 'P' ELSE 'I' END, t1.important_id_1 as important_id, ..., 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.important_id_1 = t2.important_id_2 
WHERE important_id_1 BETWEEN <range min>
ORDER BY important_id;
```

or

```
SELECT CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY important_id) WHEN (SELECT TOP (1) FROM #temptable WHERE p_record_index=<???>) THEN 'P' ELSE 'I' END, t1.important_id_1 as important_id, ..., 
FROM table1 t1 
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.important_id_1 = t2.important_id_2 
WHERE important_id_1 BETWEEN <range min> AND <range max>
ORDER BY important_id;
```

The problem with the first approach is that ROW_NUMBER() not only doesn't reference the outer query when used in the subquery, ROW_NUMBER() doesn't work at all and throws an error.

The problem with the second approach is that even though ROW_NUMBER() is at the relevant scope when called before the WHEN clause, I can't figure out how to get anything in the WHEN clause to return a matching entry in the temptable. If I do a query as in the example, then I am back to the same problem with the first approach where I need to reference ROW_NUMBER() in the subquery. I was hoping I could join #temptable on something, but what am I going to join it on, ROW_NUMBER()? Then I am at the same problem again.

No matter what I do, ROW_NUMBER() is not able to be referenced in any helpful way, so maybe I just need to give up on the #temptable route I have going. It seems like just marking a column 'P' or 'I' and leaving out some fields for 'I' records would be pretty simple so maybe I am just totally on the wrong track, but if anyone can please help me achieve this with or without this approach it would be very helpful to me and appreciated greatly. Thank you.

Comment: why is this tagged mysql & oracle?

Comment: have you tried a subquery that returns the row_number and doing logic based on it in an outer query?

Comment: @ysth Stack Overflow recommenced I use those tags so I just assumed it’d get more attention this way. That is a good idea, I haven’t thought about that and it seems like a really great thing to try. Thank you. Will let you know if it works.

Comment: @ysth please see Raihan's answer that avoids the #temptable altogether. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly. Considering an example table with data like following

[image]

Here is the sql to get your desired result set -

```
SELECT 
  Id,
  Important_Id,
  CASE WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Important_Id ORDER BY Id) = 1 
    THEN 'P' 
    ELSE 'I' 
  END P_or_I,
  OtherColumn
FROM TestTable01 
WHERE Important_Id BETWEEN 12300 AND 12346
```

This returns following result set

[image]

Keep in mind -

- It's really important to choose the correct order by field because it will change your final result.
- Partition by should refer to the field on which you are actually thinking to determine the row number starting from 1 every time for a new value of that field.

Comment: Thank you kindly, this worked perfectly well. I had even looked into partition so I was definitely spinning my wheels. This is my first non-intern position and so this is so exciting to have just run this now and have it work - thank you again!